# Filling input boxes in Bunit blazor Unit test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, razor, bunit

I have a blazor page with some input boxes and a button to submit the data.  There is then code to validate and upload the data to a database after passing validation.

```
@page "/register"

<h2>
    Create account
</h2>

<EditForm Model="_model" OnSubmit="@Submit">
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Display name</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="_handle" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="_email" type="email" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="_password" type="password" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Re-enter password</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="_repeatPassword" type="password" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="d-grid">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Submit">Create your account</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

<div>
<a href="/signin">Sign in</a>
</div>

@code {
    private object _model = new object();

    private string _firstname;
    private string _lastname;
    private string _handle;
    private string _email;
    private string _password;
    private string _repeatPassword;

    //  -- validate inputs -- //
    //  -- Add to Database -- //

           var user = new User
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Username = _email.ToLowerInvariant(),
                Handle = _handle,
                Password = password,
                PasswordSalt = passwordSalt,
                Firstname = _firstname,
                Lastname = _lastname,
                CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
            };

        context.Users.Add(user);

        await context.SaveChangesAsync(default);
}
```

Recently I decided to set up unit testing for my razor pages and I am currently stuck on how to verify that a user is actually being created with the given data.  I will say I know that my code is working because I can see the correct data being added to the database but I don't want to test potential changes in the future by looking at the database.  I would like to be able to test it by the unit test.  Here is what I have so far, I think I am close but not quite sure how to fill the input boxes and then hit submit to see the user is created. Is this possible?  My unit test code is below.

```
namespace ZachUnitTests.ZachUnitTests.Pages;

public class RegisterTests
{
    [Test]
    public void VerifyUserData()
    {
        // Arrange
        using var ctx = new Bunit.TestContext();
        
        // Act
        var cut = ctx.RenderComponent<Register>();
        
        var inputs = cut.FindAll(".form-group");

        var input1 = inputs.Where(x => x.ParentElement.TextContent.Contains("Display name")).FirstOrDefault();
        input1.Input("Zachrules123"); //doesn't work because there is no @oninput .. How do I fill this box? 
        var input2 = inputs.Where(x => x.ParentElement.TextContent.Contains("Email")).FirstOrDefault();
        input2.Input("Zachrules123@gmail.com"); //doesn't work because there is no @oninput .. How do I fill this box? 
        var input3 = inputs.Where(x => x.ParentElement.TextContent.Contains("Password")).FirstOrDefault();
        input3.Input("password"); //doesn't work because there is no @oninput .. How do I fill this box? 
        var input4 = inputs.Where(x => x.ParentElement.TextContent.Contains("Re-enter password")).FirstOrDefault();
        input4.Input("password");  //doesn't work because there is no @oninput .. How do I fill this box?
        
        cut.Find("button").Click();
        
        //Assert
        //User is created
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message from bUnit tells you what other event handler are actually bound to the object. You can also check `cut.Markup` and see what event handler are bound. But it is likely `onchange`, so use the `Change()` method instead of `Input()`.

Comment: let me start by saying thank you for bUnit It is incredible! Change() isn't working either.  It tells me there is no onchange event either.  I was hopping for a non event related solution as the code I inherited does not have an event attached to it.  Maybe that's what I should change..  Regardless I get this message `Bunit.MissingEventHandlerException: The element does not have an event handler for the event 'onchange', nor any other events.`

Comment: In that case, I would check out `cut.Markup` while debugging the test. It has the raw markup generated by your component under test, and that should give a clear indication of which elements have event handlers bound to them. Look for attributes with the name `blazor:eventName`, e.g. `blazor:onclick="1"`. Then use the matching event trigger method.